# Change progress of ProgressBar

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app where users enter a specific byte value, and I am using a work manager to mimic the uploading progress for them. So, it's basically this:

```
int size = 50000; // Depends on what kind of file size the user wants to mimic
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   //Increase progress
   UploadFile.setUploadProgress(i);
}
```

This code is in work manager. The `UploadFile.java` is my activity.

While `UploadFile.setUploadProgress(int progress)` is a static function in my activity which looks like this:

```
public static void setUploadProgress(int progress) {
   progressBar.setProgress(progress);
}
```

`progressBar` being my progress bar which is defined as:

```
private static ProgressBar progressBar;
```

But this is static, so it is logical for it to have memory leaks. I know we can use `ThreadLocal<>()` in AsyncTask to avoid this, but what can we use something inside a activity and with a static function to avoid memory leaks? Or is there a better way to do this?

If this is a duplicate, please point me to the right direction, because I couldn't find anything.

Comment: `But this is static, so it is logical for it to have memory leaks` why memory leaks?

Comment: @TaQuangTu Memory leaks happen when ui objects escape the main thread. And my progress bar is a `public static` one in my activity.

Comment: No, I don't think the problem caused by the method is static. Also this is not Memory leaks, it's is just your UI thread blocked by chain of tasks as the loop upto 50000 times.

Comment: did you try runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

Comment: My functions are actually working. The IDE is saying to me that there could be memory leaks. And no I have not tried `runOnUiThread()`. If you got any idea, please post it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WorkManager is intended for background jobs. As far as I am aware, you can output the **end result only** of WorkManager and do with it whatever you want inside the code - note that you can extend from CoroutineWorker to handle coroutines or RxWorker to handle RxJava2. If I were you, I would scope the upload progress to the running activity/fragment and dedicate the it to the WorkManager only if the app goes to background. From WorkManager, I am able to spawn Notification which will inform the user about the progress.

Comment: I know that, but the thing is that I want to show an uploading progress with the work manager continuously otherwise if I were to enqueue it when the activity was destroyed, the process would have to start over again. Something I don't want to happen.

Comment: I was keen on using the work manager to do weird UI stuff, but now I realize it shouldn't be that way. Thanks for the reminder!